# linux command - how to send a notification email using shell script to administrator

Tags: linux

How can I send in Linux a notification email using shell script to administrator 
about monitor a given sites/machines, given at runtime, and notifies an administrator by email if any of the sites/machines becomes unresponsive

Comment: for downvoters: maybe you think this should be in superuser? but it seems a programmer just needs a quick way to notify an admin account, it maybe not be necessary to move this question away (even though  `superuser` or `unix` could be better se sites to post this question at)

Answer (score 1):

send, in Linux, a notification email to administrator (I assume: local root account):

```
echo "simple ascii only message here" | mail -s "subject line" root
```

or

```
cat notification_file | mail -s "subject line"  root
#note: notification_file's content will be the "body" of your email. Not an attachment.
#It should contain only regular ASCII characters... ie, basically:
#  letters, numbers, punctuations, newlines, tabs, spaces.
#Anything else could be tricky. If you need more (unicode? attachments?),
#you should use a variant (ex: mutt ?) instead of the basic "mail" command
```

If you meant an outside mail, to a work/personnal email, you'll need to read a bit about how mail systems work, as by default it will not be able to reach the correct smtp server in the correct way...

Comment: ok thank you , but how can I notify the admin witch is local root account that the site is  becomes unresponsive